# change in arrangement of sentences in a text file in Python

Tags: python, nlp

I am new in Python and have a text file "in_file.txt" with sentences

```
in_file = ['sentence one',
           'sentence two', 
           'sentence has the word bad one', 
           'sentence four', 
           'sentence five', 
           'sentence six', 
           'sentence seven', 
           'sentence has the word bad two', 
           'sentence nine']
```

Among these, there are sentences with the word "bad" in them exactly once. I want to take the above 5 sentences of any line with the word "bad" in it and make a paragraph with them as follows (except at the beginning where there may not be 5 sentences present):

```
out_file = ['sentence one sentence two',
            'sentence has the word bad sentence four sentence five sentence six sentence seven']
```

Then save it in a file "out_file.txt". Thank you for help and please let me know if I did not provide enough explanation. Please note that maybe all the sentences in the input file do not make it to the final selection in the output file. I'm only interested in those sentences being above and within 5 sentences of another sentence with the word "bad" in it.

Just a starting point:

```
with open("in_file.txt", "r") as lines:
    for line in lines
    # maybe there is an index counter here!
    for word in line
    if word = bad
    # then take the above 5 lines
    # add to the out_file
    # return out_file
```

Comment: Can we see your attempt? HINT: seems like you have to deal with `f.readlines()`

Comment: I am working on it. I'll share as soon as the code does anything.

Comment: Your expected output is not completed and consistent. My downvote

Comment: Thank you mad_. I identified the input and output

Comment: What should happen to this sentence `sentence has the word bad two`

Comment: Nothing. If it's above and within 5 sentence of another sentence with the word bad in it, it will be chosen. If not, then many sentences such as this and others will not make it to the out_file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUCC Below is the code that should work for you

```
with open("in_file.txt", "r") as f:
    l = f.readlines()
# l = ['sentence one',
#     'sentence two',
#      'sentence has the word bad one',
#      'sentence four',
#      'sentence five',
#      'sentence six',
#      'sentence seven',
#      'sentence has the word bad two',
#      'sentence nine']
final_para=[]
previous_index=0
for index,value in enumerate(l):
    if "bad" in value:
        final_para.append(' '.join(l[previous_index:min(index,previous_index+5)]))
        previous_index=index

print(final_para)#['sentence one sentence two', 'sentence has the word bad one sentence four sentence five sentence six sentence seven']

with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in final_para:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Thank you @mad_. This does the job for me. I added a line to my question explaining what happens to some of the sentences that don't make it to the out_file. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open("in_file.txt", "r") as f:
    l = f.readlines()

# where l is 

l = ['sentence has the word bad one',
         'sentence four',
         'sentence five',
         'sentence six',
         'sentence seven',
         'sentence has the word bad two',
         'sentence nine']

# sentences with "bad"
" ".join(filter( lambda x: x.find("bad") > -1, l))
## -> 'sentence has the word bad one sentence has the word bad two'

# sentences without "bad"
" ".join(filter( lambda x: x.find("bad") == -1, l))
## -> 'sentence four sentence five sentence six sentence seven sentence nine'
```

Comment: Thank you Euclides. I want the above five sentences of any sentence with word "bad" to be a paragraph. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes the last 2 lines of code will give you a single line of text that is your paragraphs with and without the word bad.